# Image under a left adjoint functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Suppose $\psi: \mathbf{Groups} \rightarrow \mathbf{Sets}$ is a left adjoint functor. How would I go about evaluating $\psi(\mathbb{Z})$?

Since $\psi$ is left adjoint, let $\psi$ be left adjoint to a functor $\varphi: \mathbf{Sets} \rightarrow \mathbf{Groups}$. Then by definition we have a bijection between $\textrm{Mor}_{\mathbf{Groups}}(\mathbb{Z}, \varphi(S)) \overset{\sim}{\rightarrow} \textrm{Mor}_{\mathbf{Sets}}(\psi(\mathbb{Z}), S)$ for all sets $S$. Maybe it would help to study $\textrm{Mor}_{\mathbf{Groups}}(\mathbb{Z}, \varphi(S))$ but I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Are you sure it's too general? I was thinking, left adjoint functors preserve initial objects and hence $\psi$ sends the identity group to the empty set. For any group $G$, there is a unique $\textrm{Groups}$-morphism from $G \rightarrow \{e\}$ where $\{e\}$ is the identity group. Since $\psi$ is a functor, this $\textrm{Groups}$-morphism gets sent to a morphism in $\textrm{Mor}_{Sets}(\psi(G), \emptyset)$. If $\psi(G)$ was nonempty, then no such morphism exists and hence $\psi(G) = \emptyset$? Is there an error?

Comment: Oh you are right. Sorry. I've deleted my comment. So you have answered your own question, the only left adjoint functor is the one which is constant $\emptyset$. (Its right adjoint maps every set to the trivial group.)

Answer (score 1):

More generally, let $C$ be a category with a [zero object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/zero+object) $0$ and let $D$ be a category with a [strictly initial object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+initial+object) $\emptyset$. Then any left adjoint functor $F : C \to D$ maps everything to (something isomorphic to) $\emptyset$. In fact, if $x \in C$, we have a morphism $x \to 0$. Since left adjoints preserve initial objects, the image is a morphism $F(x) \to \emptyset$, which has to be an isomorphism by the choice of $\emptyset$.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same argument as the OP gave?

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: Mark as CW, maybe?